# No-crop canvas increase to 2:1 aspect ratio with ImageMagick

Tags: image, image-processing, imagemagick

I am in a situation where I have a set of images with variable width and height and I need to ensure that those images comply with an aspect ratio of 2:1.

The only assumption I can make is that those images have an aspect ratio greater than 2 so I need to expand the canvas.

With ImageMagick I can do this:

`magick input.jpg -background black -gravity north -extent 2:1 output.jpg`

But this crops instead of adding canvas as desired. Is there an option to avoid cropping, i.e. force image padding? Remember I do not know the image resolution beforehand.

Of course with a more complex script I can extract the image dimensions and compute the desired resolution but I am trying to keep things simple if possible.

P.S.: The images comes from a laser scanner and are going to be used in a 360 panorama viewer hence the need to meet an aspect ration without cropping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With ImageMagick v7 you can do some inline calculations that will adjust the results of the `-extent` operation to pad any size input to a 2:1 ratio. See this command as an example...

```
magick input.png -gravity center -extent "%[fx:max(w,h*2)]x%[fx:max(w/2,h)]" result.png
```

That will pad any extra space with black. Add `-background <somecolor>` before the extent operation to change the padding color.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for. It seems I completely overlook the documentation part about inline calculations.